# "Simplest" navigation in jQuery Mobile

Tags: ajax, navigation, jquery-mobile

Here's my code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">

    <li data-role="list-divider">foo</li>


    <li><a href="shoppingCart.htm?step=1&idOcc=123">p1</a></li>
      <li><a href="shoppingCart.htm?step=2&idOcc=346">2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I simply want to load the other page, as this one (the first viewed).

Why does it hang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not with to use AJAX to load the other page, add this to your anchor tag:

```
data-ajax="false"
```

E.g.

```
<a href="shoppingCart.htm?step=1&idOcc=123" data-ajax="false">p1</a>
```

There could be a number of reasons why the page hangs when you go to it, but trying to view it outside of an AJAX load is a good start.  Also, make sure you are using the HTML5 doctype, as jQuery Mobile requires it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: wonderful it works, thanks! :) However, I do not necessarily need to disable ajax navigation, but I can't put all "pages" in a single file. I first tought to have a single template file (html5 doctype, all right) which receives in input a parameter 'page' to know what to include, but that hangs :(

Answer (score 0):

Two more things for other cases:

Be sure you use a recent version of jQuery Mobile. Versions alpha1 and alpha2 had general problems with loading content, versions alpha2 and alpha3 had problems loading local files when not on a server.

before `data-ajax` was introduced, a `rel="external"` was used and it is still valid and I'd recommend it.